# how to get json response from wordpress website

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am developing an android app. I dont know anything about wordpress database or how to get data from the website. I googled for how to get data from the wordpress database I have got to know I could get json response from `JSON API` plugin of the wordpress. but It's hard for me to understand.

I am using food bakery theme for wordpress.

I just want to know how do I get required json response from this website. And where the data of products in that website is located in database.

for example : product,categories etc. etc

My expected response is something like this

```
{"Category":[{"ProductSubGroupCategoryCode":"PSG03","ProductGroupCategoryCode":"PG01","Description":"WRAPS"
,"CHello SirreatedBy":"101","CreatedDate":"\/Date(1486116932060)\/","ModifiedBy":null,"ModifiedDate":null}]},
{"SubCategory":[{"ProductID":"01","Description":"VEG BURGER","ReferanceID":"VEG BURGER","UOM":"EA","AlterUOM":"EA",
"ProductGroupCategoryCode":"PG01","ProductSubGroupCategoryCode":"PSG01","TaxCategoryCode":"","TaxCode":"VAT5","BuyPrice":100,
"AttributeCode":"PA01","BasicPrice":190.48,"TaxRate":5.00,"SalesPrice":200.00,"ProductImage":null,"CurrentStock":10,
"PlantCode":"PC01","StoreLocationCode":"S01","DisplayOnPOS":true,"POSDisplayOrder":0,"CreatedBy":"101",
"CreatedDate":"\/Date(1486446663333)\/","ModifiedBy":"101","ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1486447253063)\/"}
```

**Edit:**
I tried with WP REST API i have come upto, when i use this link it gives me response with id 1 `http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1`.
when when I have tried with other post IDs it gives me blank response.

FYI I got post ID for that certain post from `wordpress_posts` table of wordpress database

Answer (score 4):

```
if you want to get post:
```

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

```
if you want to get a particular post
```

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1852

```
 whereas 1852 is the id of the post
```

Comment: Not sure why the op did not set this answer as correct. Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For getting JSON response from word press site you need to install certain open source plugin on word press site
here is an WP API link 
Click [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAp-_o8PvTAhUJpY8KHfuTBGoQFghEMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fv2.wp-api.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNH9NoJZyrpzs3TaIB2HWYQsR6AG-Q&sig2=9m_yuTVlwjoQ169Z-1utfA)
As per documentation You can also create custom API

Comment: hi Siddharth Thakyou for your response, I check this API. But it sends response of all the products on that page. What if i want to load only certain products

Comment: Please read that documentation carefully. There is an option to get single post or page

Comment: I tried it now problem is I found one of my post item in the WordPress database table 'wordpress_posts` `with ID = 1342` How can i access this? I have tried it with `http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/4223`

Comment: It gives this response {"code":"rest_post_invalid_id","message":"Invalid post ID.","data":{"status":404}}

Comment: try to get post id from wordpress dashboard. There is also an option to get a single post by a slug

Comment: Can you answer how one can modify the wp-json response for a specific post only See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330395/how-to-modify-title-in-wp-json-response-but-only-for-a-specific-post

Answer (score 0):

You can access your posts json on wordpress with

> `http://oursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`